# Transfer data of Local variable used inside a function in javascript to Global Variable / or copy to a global Variable [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i used local variable outside when it will only activate once i called it in a function.. I want to transfer value after activating it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var localVariable = 'something here'
});
```

// now how  to use localvariable it outside

Comment: please explain more briefly what you are trying to do

Comment: i want to get the value of a local variable and transfer it to a new variable outside the function so i can use it

Comment: answered check it please click on document to test it

Comment: it shows localvariable is not defined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.

Comment: please show me your code

Comment: yep i think i just mistype I finally got the answer thanks!

Comment: Consider a green tick

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable and then set the value of global variable to local variable, like this
As document ready global variable has not any value, but when you  click on document it get the value and have value of local variable and then you can call it anywhere

```js
var globalvariable = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log(globalvariable);
});

$(document).click(function(){
  var localvariable = 20;
  globalvariable = localvariable;
  console.log(globalvariable);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Consider a green tick!

Comment: Quick question: how can I use  globalvariable outside the $(document).click(function(){ }???

Comment: just use it's name